# Dependency Injection with database models

Tags: java, mongodb, design-patterns, dependency-injection, orm

I'm using a ORM/ODM ([morphia](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.3/getting-started/quick-tour/)) to manage my models, but I'm running into an issue:

The constructor of a model is only called upon creation of the object (`new MyObject(dep1, dep2)`), and is not called upon being loaded from db (`db.get(id)`).

**How does one inject non-serializable dependencies into an ORM-managed object?**

I've been injecting dependencies directly into any methods that require it ie.

```
public void doSomething(UserDAO userDAO) { ... }
```

But this quickly leads to ugly code. Is there a better way?

Comment: Usually you would not hand the DAO over to a domain object. The code that operates the DAOs would rather reside in some service in the appropriate architectural layer of your application. In that case you would have the DAO injected into the service and use it together with the domain objects/models in the service code. If you have to keep the architecture as is, let's see if somebody knows a neat trick to influence the object creation in morphia.

Comment: This site lives from questioning answering and accepting flow. Since you are new here please don't forget to accept an answer see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set non-serializable dependencies to your entities after loading them then you can use the lifecycle annotation `@PostLoad` [[Life Cycle Methods]](https://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.1/guides/lifeCycleMethods/).

In example

```
@PostLoad
void postLoad() {
   userDAO = // e.g. new UserDAO() or UserDAO.getInstance();
}
```

---

Although this is possible I don't say that this is a good approach. You should consider to separate your entities (domain objects) and service functions (application layer) (see [SoC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)).

But don't get me wrong this doesn't means that your domain objects should not contain any logic at all.